# ORACLE/PLSQL: No data found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

So before I start, I think I understand why I am getting the error. It's because I am using before trigger and if there are no values for `home_id` already inserted before it won't show anything.  But the thing is, I used the same trigger before and it worked.

So here is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trgpick 
    BEFORE insert or update on picking 
    for each row 
declare
    v_count number:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count 
    FROM home 
    WHERE home_ID=:NEW.home_ID;
    IF v_count>4 then
        :new.time:=9;
    ELSIF v_count<5then 
        :new.time:=3;
    END IF;
END;
```

So when I execute this trigger and insert a value in it with an actual `Home_id`, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) returns 0 if the count is actually 0 and not an error, so the issue must be somewhere else. Can you expose the tables you have with some data.

Comment: Which line gives the error? Is there anything else in the error stack? Any chance of a [test case](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)? Otherwise we all have to create two tables and a trigger to check what it might be.

Comment: I created the tables and trigger and inserted a row, and it worked without error. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get ':NEW' value if you use before action,then you probably need to use after action trigger or go with :OLD qualifier.